# Click each element then scrape with horseman

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a node.js module called horseman to scrape some data from a site which contains JavaScript. I'm having trouble figuring out how to click on each span element IF it contains a certain element within it, table in this case. This will expand that element and produce data available to scrape, which right now is hidden.

What I have right now

```
horseman
    .open(url)
    .click("span.title")
    .waitforSelector("span.title")
    .then(scrape)
```

The scrape function:

```
function scrape() {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        return getLinks()
            .then(function (newLinks) {

                links = links.concat(newLinks);


                if (links.length < 1)
                    return horseman

                        .then(scrape);

            }
            })
        .then(resolve);
});
    }
```

And the getlinks function()

```
var links = [];

function getLinks() {

    return horseman.evaluate(function () {
        var links = [];
        $("span.title").each(function (item) {
            var link = {
                title: $(this).text()
            };
            links.push(link);
        });
        return links;
    });
}
```

My initial thoughts were that in the getLinks() function I could check if item contains table then click and then scrape, but not sure how to implement it. 
The idea is to expand all the span elements, that are not already expanded, which means the data is visible and able to be scraped. I've hit a brick wall on what to do, so any help would be great!

Comment: You say a click reveals somecontent, but this content might be scrapable immediately even though it is hidden? Did you have a look in the page markup? Or does the content arrives later in the page - for example via ajax?

Comment: Also, isn't it `.click('span.title').waitforSelector('span.title')`? (quotes) Note: If you click on a selector, you don't need to wait for this same selector, if something is clickable, it also already exists, hence it will be returned immediately : the `waitForSelector` method doesn't wait for *change*, but for *presence* : https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman#waitforselectorselector

Comment: I had a look at the page source, the content only appears after you expand the elements. Sorry i missed the quotes!

Comment: Ok, so I guess the problem is that your `waitForElement` is not waiting anything, because the selector is present already, so it returns the elements after the click, but most probably before the content appears. Can you try with `.wait(1000)` instead, just to infirm or confirm this?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question. I know it should wait. But i don't know how i should click each span element to expand them and then scrape the data.

Comment: Ok that's the click that is not working, sorry I did'nt get it indeed :) Let me try an answer because according to horseman sourcecode, the click action seem to occur on a single element only, not many

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code :

```
    horseman
        .open(url)
        .click("span.title")
        .waitforSelector("span.title")
        .then(scrape)
```

...will not work because `.click()` horseman action only address single elements. Instead, you can try the following code that will work on many elements :

```
    horseman
        .open(url)
        .evaluate(clickItems)
        .waitforSelector("span.title XXX")
        .then(scrape)
```

Where :

- `XXX` should be the selector of the content inside the span.title (so the waitForSelector will actually wait). For example, let's consider this markup :

  `<span class="title"><!-- this is the clickable item -->
    <table>...</table>
    <div class="show-on-click">Blah blah</div>
  </span>`

In the above example, you would use `.waitForSelector('span.item .show-on-click')`. You have to find which selector does not exist until the data appears. (or use `.wait(1000)` instead)

- clickItem function is defined as following (I see that you use jQuery so I will as well)

  ```
  function clickItems() {
      var $items = $('span.title:has(table)');

      $items.each(function(index, $item) {
          $item.click();
      });
  }
  ```

*Note: This will click on all the elements `span.title`. You can modify the click element to add a table presence test in each `$item`, but I guess you can omit that if the other clicks do not do anything.*

Comment: Edited my answer to be more precise. Also I made a mistake in the clickItems function ($items.each, instead of $item.each)

Comment: So how/where would i check if the span element now contains a table element THEN click?

Comment: Edited. That part is simple jQuery, you would use `span.title:has(table)` instead of just `span.title` cf. https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: Can't seem to get this working. I inspected the code and seems as though nothing happens. What it you didn't use jquery and just javascript?

Comment: @Pandaiolo can you please help me out for my  question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538705/cant-click-on-button-using-horseman?noredirect=1#comment74129631_43538705